# (Laravel/PHP) How to save file in memory or delete file before return without causing error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

(It's API only) I'm using **JasperPHP** to generate reports, the user can choose the extension (xls or pdf). After I process the data, then I save the file/report locally, it's in `"storage/app/jasper/example1234.pdf"`.

So at the end of the function I do this:

```php
    // more code
    $file = $path . $filename . '.' . $extension; // file path
    // more code
    return response()->file($file);
```

And it works, I can get the file using ReactJS. OK! But I wanted to delete the file before the "return", but if I do that the file will not be read on the "return". That's why I wanted to save it in a variable/memory first, delete the file locally and then return.

Note I tried to get the file using several methods, such as `"Storage::get()"`, but they all generate errors on "return", stating that "string file" is expected but "resource" was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response facade has `deleteFileAfterSend()` method. You can use it like the following:

```php
return response()->file($file)->deleteFileAfterSend();
```

Comment: Oh my god, how simple hahaha. I'm new to Laravel/PHP and I got a project in progress, so I didn't have time to study in depth. Thank you very much!